# What are the touch-centric development benefits of moving a windows WPF desktop application to a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-8, windows-7

I have a WPF/MVVM application running on windows 7. Most of my users have windows 7 machines but I would like to develop an enhanced touch-enabled version for windows 8 but need to keep the windows 7 version up to date. The app currently works as is on windows 8 with touches acting as clicks. Not including the ability to run on an rt tablet, what benefits would I gain from this rewrite? The purpose for the expansion is to take an application with a lot of repetitive clicking and make it more efficient and less of a strain on long-term users. The application will likely never need to run on a tablet as it requires a lot of screen space and visual inspection of multiple images.

For example, are there specific gestures like pinch and zoom which are markedly easier to implement in windows store apps than WPF?

I have struggled with how to ask this question, so if I've missed the pertinent title, I'd be happy to change it for clarity.

Comment: I think it is off-topic (maybe programmers or UX) as it has no code. Anyway, it has the benefits of going native: better use of the machine capabilities (in this case UI) that just "emulating" the old platform (mouse & keyboard). Of course, there will be a benefit IF you design it correctly.

Comment: Yes, even if it isn't off-topic, you will probably get better answers on UX, anyway

Comment: I suppose a more code centric question would ask about a specific desired interaction and then evaluate the difference in coding that interaction between .net or rt. However Filip's answer below did provide me with an overview of the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My 2c

**Benefits of WinRT/XAML**

1. You get controls designed for touch - they look more touch friendly, respond to touch better and some of them are unique to WinRT. That can save you at the very least a lot of the time you might otherwise need to spend retemplating WPF controls.
2. You get a ScrollViewer that pans and zooms smoothly with touch. You get one that pans for WPF with the [Surface SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716), but I'm not sure if it might not be as responsive. 
   *The Surface SDK is also getting a bit old (VS 2012, WPF 4.0) and I'm not sure if it's ideal for desktop. One example I recall from the big Surface times is you can press multiple buttons at the same time which might not be ideal.*
3. You get all the list controls that use a `ScrollViewer` and pan and virtualize nicely like a `ListView`, `GridView` or `FlipView`.
4. You get the `AppBar` and edge gestures.
5. You get great integration with a browser control (`WebView`), the latest DirectX and Media Foundation (mic, camera, video, audio).
6. You get a `TextBox` that integrates well with the virtual keyboard, allows selection with touch etc.
7. Lots of other smaller controls.
8. Decent high DPI support.
9. Selling the app publicly is easier.
10. You get new, responsive async APIs and learn a new framework that might be the future.
11. You get to reuse most of the skills you might have gained learning WPF.

**Benefits of WPF**

1. Enterprise deployment might be simpler (depending on scale and existing infrastructure you have for a WPF app).
2. You don't have to rewrite your code or wire up two very different frameworks that might not work well with some development tools. Rewrites typically take more time than it seems from early estimates and often bring a lot of bugs and limitations that the old versions of software didn't have.
3. You can keep using and advancing your existing skills.
4. Lots of legacy frameworks and libraries available to you.
5. No Windows Store App sandbox limitations.
6. Lots of powerful controls in the platform and 3rd party libraries that might not necessarily work great with touch, but are very powerful for mouse and keyboard. Especially various `DataGrids` and possibly charts and others. Also hosting Office document views and any other ActiveX things.
7. WPF still has future for the desktop and might gain some of the features or controls that are currently WinRT/XAML only. Watch [Windows Desktop Development: A Panel Discussion](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-563) and [XAML, WPF and Other Fairy Tales](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/9-005) from Build 2014.
8. More mature tooling (Snoop!)
9. More mature platform overall that's not as likely to change as much under your feet as the hot and new one typically does.

Comment: Thanks. That provided a lot of the sort of information I was looking for. Answers 1,2  and 3 especially. I have a pretty good idea of the UI I'm going for, I'm mostly trying to figure out if it would be easier to code it for rt or if I can achieve enough sticking with win 7 completely.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you're using MVVM, if you move your view model logic to a separate assembly you will reduce the amount of work needed to support two applications. Effectively, you will have two apps but with a common logic layer. You can write a win 8 version with emphasis on touch, and maintain your click focused win 7 version.

Really you need to decide if you need touch. You will have access to manipulations such as rotate and pinch as well as potential multi touch gestures. If your app only needs click and scroll, then don't waste your time. Also, how many of your users actually have touch screens? I work in a team of 30 devs running win 8.1 and we only have two touchscreen users.

Comment: The only touch screen user I'll have will be the employee that takes the touch development machine and uses the new app. If I can save her wrists and improve her efficiency simultaneously it'll be worth it. Its a research data analysis application, if distributed will probably be open-sourced anyway. For example, how much easier is rotate and pinch on rt, or rather is it only available on rt? That's an interaction that would likely be needed.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about RT, not sure who uses that :) focus on windows store.